# Will macOS Mojave 10.14 slow down an early 2011 13" MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, mojave

I am currently running OS X El Capitan on my early 2011 13" MacBook Pro. I am thinking of upgrading to macOS Mojave, but would like to know if it would slow my MacBook Pro because of my specs?

Please see more info on the specs below:

[image]

I'm not using an SSD and my current available space is 140GB (total is 320GB), though I always make sure I don't go below 100GB available space.

Comment: In my experience, High Sierra is more performant than El Capitan. Mavericks is more performant than both, and is what I would use if I was in your situation—but since it's not getting security updates, I can't really recommend that per se.

Answer (score 1):

As Nimesh already noted in his answer, that MacBook Pro is no longer supported.

But as chriszanf commented: "Machines outside of those spec can be upgraded using dosdude's app: [dosdude1.com/mojave](http://dosdude1.com/mojave/)"

But apart from being unsupported that brings another caveat. Just installing that will work, but is no fine experience at all. For once, the installer will convert your magnetic drive HDD from HFSplus to APFS, and the new filesystem is a terrible performer in general and even much worse on rotational disks. That will slow you down.

[Using APFS on hdds and why you might not want to](https://blog.macsales.com/43043-using-apfs-on-hdds-and-why-you-might-not-want-to)

You also have to keep in mind that your graphics card is not exchangeable and does not supported [Metal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_(API)). That will slow you down.

The problems do not end there. And the list of hacks and workarounds you might have to hunt down is also long.

It is possible to install it. But probably not really worth it.

If you have some time on your hand, the following thread lists some experiences in attempting this:

[macOS 10.14 Mojave on Unsupported Macs Thread](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/macos-10-14-mojave-on-unsupported-macs-thread.2121473/page-2) and it is very conveniently just 471 pages long by now.

<sub>Personal commentary: on that hardware 10.12 Sierra is the last "known good" performer for me. That is currently at least also updated with security patches.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The highest version of macOS supported on your MacBook Pro is macOS High Sierra 10.13. macOS Mojave requires a Mac with support for Metal (2012 and later Macs).

- [macOS High Sierra - Technical Specifications](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP765)
- [macOS Mojave - Technical Specifications](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP777).

As per the General Requires mentioned in the linked technical specifications page, you should be fine running macOS High Sierra. Overall performance will depend on the kind and number of apps running simultaneously on your Mac.

> ## macOS High Sierra - Technical Specifications
>
> ### General Requirements
>
> - OS X 10.8 or later
> - 2GB of memory
> - 14.3GB of available storage to perform upgrade*
> - Some features require an Apple ID; terms apply.
> - Some features require a compatible Internet service provider; fees may apply.

Comment: Interestingly the App Store is only giving me options to upgrade to Mojave. I thought it's curated based on system requirements

Comment: Machines outside of those spec can be upgraded using dosdudes app: http://dosdude1.com/mojave/

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about the specs of your MacBook Pro affecting performance, then change the specs! You can very easily open the bottom case and add more memory, which will help enormously. Swapping the hard drive for an SSD in a Unibody is also fairly straightforward. (I'd recommend getting a USB to SATA connector, so you can connect and clone/copy one drive to another before or after the swap.)

RAM and an SSD will cost comparatively little, and breathe much new life into your old Mac. Then you can worry about upgrading.